# How to format (line no, filename) in python logbook to write into log file?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, logbook

Example to update ogs in the file:

2016-10-06 07:04:21 ERROR file.py line no: 120 Index Error

Answer (score 0):

The docs are your friend

logging to a file:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

changing the format of the message:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages

more info on dates and logging:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(levelname)s line no: %(lineno)d %(message)s', filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Comment: I want to do it in python log book instead of python logging..Thanks for ur rply